# Variable declaration (Dim) and assignment in 1 statement

Tags: vb.net, vb6-migration

I have noticed in VB.Net that most Dim statements also include an assignment. Eg:

```
Dim myvar As String = "Hello World"
```

As this wasn't possible in VB6 I have always done the following:

```
Dim myvar As String
myvar = "Hello World"
```

Are there any advantages/disadvantages to either style?

Comment: In VB6 this wasn't possible! You had to write two lines.

Comment: @dwo Oh yes you're right! It must have been a ghost memory. How strange. I'll edit the question to clarify the VB6 references then. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no advantage/disadvantage for the first over the second, for both functionalities are same.

Answer (score 1):

Since current versions of VB.NET support type inference (`Option Infer On`), you also have a third option:

```
Dim myvar = "Hello World"
```

This is equivalent to the other two options.

- The advantage is that it is more concise (the data type is obvious anyway in this example),
- the disadvantage is that the data type might not be obvious in all cases (`Dim myvar = SomeMethod()`).

With respect to the two options presented by you, I would always prefer the first over the second option, since it avoids duplication and, thus, lowers the risk of typos. In addition, such code can be read faster since the reader does not have to compare the variable names.

Comment: +1, usually when declaring a variable you also want to initialize it to some value, so you might as well do it all in one step.